# How to disable strict const check during compile using gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I'm doing some compile works recently.
After updated openssl1.1.1f to openssl1.1.1h, I met some compile errors for packages using the openssl headers "bio.h" and "evp.h".
That's because openssl1.1.1h add something like this:

```
/*
 * name is cast to lose const, but might be better to route through a
 * function so we can do it safely
 */
#ifdef CONST_STRICT
/*
 * If you are wondering why this isn't defined, its because CONST_STRICT is
 * purely a compile-time kludge to allow const to be checked.
 */
int BIO_read_filename(BIO *b, const char *name);
# else
#  define BIO_read_filename(b,name) (int)BIO_ctrl(b,BIO_C_SET_FILENAME, \
                BIO_CLOSE|BIO_FP_READ,(char *)(name))
# endif
```

If the CONST_STRICT marco is defined, you have to implement the api yourself otherwise you will get an undefined reference error during linkage phase.
I wonder what compile option I have to add to make the CONST_STRICT marco NOT defined?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you *sure* that you need to implement this function yourself, and that you're not simply forgetting to link with some library?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  I searched the libraries generated by libopenssl compilation, none of these functions is found.

Comment: Your question is : how to undefine CONST_STRICT ? why not commenting out the  `#define CONST_STRICT` that should be somewhere in a .h file or project setting  ?

Comment: as explained, the macro `BIO_read_filename` is only a trick to get rid of the `const`qualifier and avoid compilation error. You may implement a real function instead of this macro, which would manage to const to unconst "conversion".

Comment: @Guillaume Petitjean
Maybe I miss-understood what the comment in the openssl header means? The marco CONST_STRICT is not automatically generated by the compilation process  but defined by someone who want's to use some user defined api manually?

Comment: that's indeed what I understand. I would expect this macro CONST_STRICT is not defined by default.

Comment: If someone want's to implement the api themselves, they just need to define the CONST_STRICT marco and implement the api themselves?

Comment: Walker, Aside: safe macro practice:  use `()` around each argument.  `... BIO_ctrl(b,BIO_C_SET_FILENAME ...` --> `... BIO_ctrl((b),BIO_C_SET_FILENAME ...`.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica
 Yeah, you are right but that's what I copied from the openssl header ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I miss-understood what the comment in the openssl header file means, thanks to Guillaume Petitjean who corrected me.
The error I got is due to other cause. One of my packages has an older version of openssl in it, and it installed it's header files after it's being built. In that version the api BIO_read_filename was not implemented by marco definition but in a source file. I modified the makefile of the package to not install the older openssl header file and the error are gone.